# How do I upgrade to Windows 10 if I have less than 8 GB free?

Tags: windows-8, download, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation

I have an ASUS X205TA with MS Windows 8.1.  This has a 32 GB drive, but it also uses WIMBoot and has a recovery partition.  I am unable to get more than 7.5 GB of free space.

Microsoft offer a Windows 10 media creation tool to allow people to create a USB stick to upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

I place a newly formatted 16 GB USB stick in. I download the tool from Windows. I start the tool.  The tool doesn't ever ask me where to download the stuff.  I step through the tool, it gathers info, and it stops with the error message "We need 8 GB of disc space. Remove any files or apps that you no longer need, or use Disk Cleanup to create some space, then try again".

**How do I upgrade to Windows 10 with the limited amount of drive space I have available?** Especially if the media creation tool can't do it.

Comment: The "at least 8GB free" is for caching the Windows 10 install files... it you can't find the minimum requirements then you'll have to use another machine (that *does* have the minimum requirements) to create the USB. Can't you upgrade to Windows 10 through Windows update? This is roughly a 2GB download...?

Comment: @BigChris Oh, I'll try that.  It seemed to be downloading a lot more than that, but I'll give that a try. It's the easier option.  I'll update after I've done it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Microsoft Employee [explained it his show on channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Lots-of-Windows-10-Stick-PCs-PST-tips-Zombie-Libraries-and-more#time=0m36s). You need 2 empty USB flash drives. Put the Win10 files from the ISO on 1 drive. The 2nd one must be empty and during running setup.exe from the 1st USB drive, it shows you that you need more space, select here the 2nd empty drive as temporary drive (`Choose another drive or attached external drive`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks magicandre1981! I added another flash drive and the upgrade is happening lol.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and found here easy solution. the only different is that I did the emulation with chrome and not with edge as discribed:
https://pureinfotech.com/download-windows-10-iso-without-media-creation-tool/

ALSO pay attention that you cant save the file on fat32 filesystem since its >4G size! you will have to convert it to nfts with windows "convert" command.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score -3):

if you search on google: windows 10, it will bring you to their site and it says "Upgrade your PC now" this way you download a little tool and it will start working on the update. also what @big chris said, you can use another computer to create the installation USB. have in mind that the windows installation on your USB will completely format your usb